# VLOOKUP with wildcards used in unique IDs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, comparison, formula, vlookup

I have a unique problem, similar questions have been asked online but I have not found a solid solution. I have two massive excel files with unique IDs that incorporate a random array of * (wild cards) used within the unique ID. I have tried to replace the * values which does not appear to work in excel. I need to compare the values in both files to identify which values are missing from the first spread sheet.

Is there a way to conduct a VLOOKUP in excel to identify missing values between two sheets given this unique wild card scenario?

Are there other tools aside from excel that could be used?

Thank you,

Comment: You can try [Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-what-is-power-query)

Comment: "Unique" and "random" are essentially incompatible concepts. However, what's the structure of your IDs? What's the interpretation of "incorporate"? If your ID is like ABCDEFG12345HGT, where letters are the ID and numbers are the incorporated random element, that element might be removed by simple character count, provided its always in the same place and of predeterminable length. The remaining ID might be less unique, however.

Comment: I'm confused, could you provide an example of what one of these IDs looks like? Is there anyway to differentiate the "wild cards" vs the non-wild card characters in the ID?

Comment: There is no pattern to identify a pattern within the wildcards. An example would be xxx*x*s*f****sds* or 867***896**45*23.

Comment: Some sample data would help in this case

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that by "... unique IDs that incorporate a random array of * (wild cards) used within the unique ID." you mean your IDs may contain literal `*` characters.

As you have seen, the search term in `VLOOKUP` treats `*` as a wildcard.  To look up a literal `*` you must delimit it using `~`

To demonstrate, you can do a `Substitute` of `*` with `~*` in your VLOOKUP formula, like this

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(C1,"*","~*"),A:A,1,0)),"Missing","Found")
```

[image]

Comment: Chris, Thank you for your support. I tried your suggestion and it returns every value as missing. I know that at least some of the values are present. I am working between two workbooks. I used "...,"~*"),Sheet_name!B2:x69786,1,FALSE)),..." where sheet_name is the workbook name and range, 1 is where the missing or found value should be returned next to the look up value and False to require an exact match.

Comment: For a reference to another Workbook, that formula is wrong.  From memory its `[WorkbookName.xlxs]WorksheetName!RangeAddress`

Comment: The workbooks are all within the same excel file. The data sets are in different tabs.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the names of Excels components.  An Excel file is a Work _book_.  A Workbook contains Work _sheet_ s